# Wayfair product prices

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure if there's an API for this but I'm trying to scrape the price of certain products from Wayfair.

I wrote some python code using Beautiful Soup and requests but I'm getting some HTML which mentions `Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network`.

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
headers = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'
 }
 
def fetch_wayfair_price(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    print(soup)
 
 fetch_wayfair_price('https://www.wayfair.ca/furniture/pdp/mistana-katarina-5-piece-extendable-solid-wood-dining-set-mitn2584.html')
```

Comment: You haven't provided the complete URL in your code snippet.

Comment: I fixed the url in my code

Comment: Use a request Session and add upgrade-insecure-requests:1 to your header.

Answer (score 0):

The Wayfair site loads a lot of data in after the initial page, so just getting the html from the URL you provided probably won't be all you need. That being said, I was able to get the request to work.

Start by using a session from the requests libary; this will track cookies and session. I also added `upgrade-insecure-requests: '1'` to the headers so that you can avoid some of the issue that HTTPS introduce to scraping. The request now returns the same response as the browser request does, but the information you want is probably loaded in subsequent requests the browser/JS make.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'dnt': '1'
}


def fetch_wayfair_price(url):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(post.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)


fetch_wayfair_price(
    'https://www.wayfair.ca/furniture/pdp/mistana-katarina-5-piece-extendable-solid-wood-dining-set-mitn2584.html')
```

Note: The session that the requests libary creates really should persist outside of the `fetch_wayfair_price` method. I have contained it in the method to match your example.